# Asp.net mvc 5: Partial view with strongly typed model of type list is not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am calling partial view controller through J_Query, controller action(ListInventoryProduct) is called and execute without error( the list is populated). But the partial view is not displayed. 
In browser Developer tool says it is internal server error.
I can't figure out what is the problem.
The following is my code.

Model:

```
public class InventoryProductsViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "SubCategory Name")]
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Balance")]
    public int Balance { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Count")]
    public int InventoryCount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Difference")]
    public string Difference { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "IMEINumber")]
    public string IMEINumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "BarrcodesString")]
    public string BarrcodesString { get; set; }
    public long subId { get; set; }
    // public List<Category> lstCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult LoadInventoryProducts(long categoryId)
{
    Session["Products"] = null;
    Session["InventoryMissing"] = null;
    var userSession = Session.GetSessionUserInfo();
    if (userSession != null)
    {
        List<InventoryProductsViewModel> products = db.Products.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.CompanyId == userSession.CompanyId && (categoryId == 0 || p.SubCategory.CategoryId == categoryId)).Select(p => new InventoryProductsViewModel { Id = p.Id, Title = p.Title, SubCategory = p.SubCategory.Title, IMEINumber = p.IMEINumber, Balance = (p.PurchasedQuantity - p.SoldQuantity) }).ToList(); //&& (subCategoryId == 0 || p.SubCategoryId == subCategoryId)
        Session["Products"] = products;
        if (Session["InventoryMissing"] == null)
        {
            Session["InventoryMissing"] = new List<InventoryMissing>(); 
            return PartialView("ProductsPartialView", products);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("~/Error/Error");
        }
    }
}
```

PartialView

```
@model List<ViewModel.InventoryProductsViewModel>
<table >
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model[0].Title)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model[0].SubCategory)</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Balance")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Count")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Difference")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("IMEI Number")</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
    {
        <tr id="@Model[i].Id">
            <td>
                @Html.Hidden(Model[i].subId)
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model[i].Title)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model[i].SubCategory)</td>
            <td class="balance">@Html.DisplayFor(Model[i].Balance)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(Model[i].InventoryCount)</td>
            <td class="difference">0</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>Model[i].IMEINumber)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: You haven't even shown the jquery code, but generally internal server error is as a result of your controller method throwing an exception

Comment: I have mentioned in question that there is no issue in J-Query code and controller action is not throwing any exception(I have debugged it).

Comment: Put break point in the partial. If there is not a problem there, then there is a problem with the ajax code.

Comment: in Partial view break points does not hit.
For your clarity, this is J_Query code
    function GetProducts(categoryId) {
            $("#catId").val(categoryId);
               $.get('LoadInventoryProducts', { 'categoryId': categoryId },
                   function (response) {
                       $('#InventoryProducts').html(response);
                                      return true;
                   })
        }

Comment: Therefore `return PartialView("ProductsPartialView", products);` is never hit. Debug you code!

Answer (score 0):

Html Helpers For Model were used which was creating problem.
Correct Helpers are as follow.

```
@model List<HiTechPOS.ViewModel.InventoryProductsViewModel>

<table class=" table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Product Name")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("SubCategory Name")
    </th>
    <th>
       @Html.Label("Balance")
    </th>
    <th>
       @Html.Label("Count")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Difference")
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.Label("IMEI Number")
    </th>
</tr>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
{
    <tr id="@Model[i].Id">
        @*<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>*@
        <td>
            @Html.Hidden(Model[i].subId.ToString())
            @Html.Label(Model[i].Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label(Model[i].SubCategory)
        </td>
        <td class="balance">
            @Html.Label(Model[i].Balance.ToString())
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Editor(Model[i].InventoryCount.ToString())
        </td>
        <td class="difference">
            @Html.Label(Model[i].Difference.ToString())
        </td>
        <td>
            if(Model[i].IMEINumber == null)
                {
                    @Html.Label("")
            }
            else
                { 
                @Html.Label(Model[i].IMEINumber)
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```